# Jquery Ajax get call using coldfusion 9: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I am new to AJAX so I apologize to begin with.

I am attempting to pull data from a database in a cfc component  using `<cfquery>` and then converting it to JSON with the `serializeJSON(var)` function. But in firebug I end up at a “unexpected Character” error. The query does have file paths in it, so could that have anything to do with the problem, or am I going about the AJAX call all wrong?

```
<cfcomponent>
<cffunction name="getStuff" access="remote" returnFormat="json">
    <cfargument name="userID" type="numeric" required="yes">
    <cfset datasrc = “data">
    <cfset pass = "">
    <cfquery datasource="#datasrc#" password="#pass#" name="getData" maxrows="25">
            SELECT blah
                FROM blah
                WHERE blah = ‘#userID#'
    </cfquery>
    <cfset jsondata = serializeJSON(getData)>
    <cfdump var="jasondata">
    <cfreturn jsondata>
</cffunction>
```

Javascript:

```
function populateBrews(id) {    
$.ajax({

    url: "/components/Object.cfc"

  , type: "get"

  , dataType: "json"

  , data: {
  method: "getStuff"

 , userId: id
 }

 , success: function (data){
 }

, error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
alert(errorThrown);
}
});
}
```

Comment: what does `alert(xhr.responseText)` return within the error callback? better yet, console.log it to ensure you aren't getting any extra characters before or after the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are JSON-ifying your JSON. See how you have returnFormat=json in the function? That tells CF to take the result and turn it into JSON. But, you are creating a JSON string yourself when you return the result. So basically, you are serializing the already serialized result. Change

```
<cfset jsondata = serializeJSON(getData)>
<cfdump var="jasondata">
<cfreturn jsondata>
```

to

```
<cfreturn getData>
```

Comment: ahh well that is not something we want, I made the change but the error is still there.

Comment: So what does Firebug show you? Can you put the response in a Pastebin and then put the link here?

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token ‘<‘ is all I get in an alert. Firebug isn’t throwing anything as of now.

Comment: A parse error on `<` sounds like what is happening is you are getting a coldfusion error. Have you tried hitting the cfc directly without ajax? `/components/Object.cfc?method=getStuff&userid=5`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have request debugging turned off - the debugging output will break the json parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: use json2.js

```
var postdata = new Object(); 
postdata.parameter1 = <value>; 
postdata.parameter2 = <value>;  

$.ajax({  
type: "POST",  
url: "url",  
dataType: "application/json",  //this is important
data: JSON.stringify(postdata),  
async: true,  
success: function (data) { Handler_Success(data); }  
});  
});
```

Comment: Changing the datatype to `application/json` doesn't matter, all that option does is specify what type of data is being returned so jquery can properly parse it for you. `"json"` will work fine. As far as stringifying the postdata, that is also not required, jquery will take the postdata object and convert it into url parameters to be sent to the cfc.

Comment: If you were trying to specify to the server that you are sending `application/json`, then you would use the `contentType` option.

Comment: I agree. Its always better to avoid mistakes which may result because of some human error. The method I mentioned above is a little safe when you are passing multiple parameters as your JSON data :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm certain Ray's answer is the right one. Your function should keep returnformat=json and just return the getData resultset without any modification.

If you're developing on Windows, I'd recommend using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and using that to watch the requests form your browser and the response from CF. Use the RAW and JSON Response inspectors to see exactly what CF is returning. We've often had to add the code below to our remove CFC methods, to make sure no other output which would break the JSON is included:

Answer (score 0):

As many of the answers alluded to, check your XHR.responseHeader... most likely your data is returning something like `<WDDX packet version='1.0'><header/><data>...` followed by your JSON-formatted response.

If this is the case add `responsetype='JSON'` to remove the WDDX formatting.